# Javascript Resizing - IndexSizeError: Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This script works fine on Chrome.

It spreads tons of errors on Firefox.

Here's the code that's giving errors :

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d'),
    img = new Image,
    sourceWidth = coordinates(one).w,
    sourceHeight = coordinates(one).h,
    sourceX = coordinates(one).x,
    sourceY = coordinates(one).y;

    img.src = coordinates(one).image;

    img.onload = function() {
    // draw image
    ctx.drawImage(img, sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight, 0, 0, width, height);
```

And these coordinates come from the other function :

```
// get cropped coordinates
        coordinates = function coordinates(self) {

            var imgInfo = self.imgInfo,
                c = self.eles.container,
                img = self.eles.img,
                imgsrc = img.attr('src'),

                coordinates = {
                    x: (parseInt(img.css('left'))) * (imgInfo.aw / (imgInfo.w * imgInfo.s)),
                    y: (parseInt(img.css('top'))) * (imgInfo.ah / (imgInfo.h * imgInfo.s)),
                    w: (c.width() - (40*2)) * (imgInfo.aw / (imgInfo.w * imgInfo.s)),
                    h: (c.height() - (40*2)) * (imgInfo.ah / (imgInfo.h * imgInfo.s)),
                    image: imgsrc
                };

            // return coodinates
            return coordinates;
        }
```

I want the image to be resized with the slider, and centered. It's working perfectly on Chrome.

What can I do ? Here's the URL to test the code:  nestecha.fr/cropScript

Comment: What are the errors you're getting?

Comment: Exactly this :

IndexSizeError: Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount
 

...x.drawImage(img, sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight, 0, 0, width, heigh...

Comment: @AlexP Error is the Question's title.

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle please ? (http://jsfiddle.net) What result do you expect and what result do you actually get ? What are the errors you get and where are they trhown ?

Comment: I added it on http://nestecha.fr/cropScript.

Try it on Chrome, I expect the exact same result.
Simply using the slider, the image should resize to get smaller and smaller in the left canvas (that works).
Then, clicking on Crop should generate the new resized image on the right (that doesn't work and throws errors quoted above).